# Call a method when an object (specifically an object) is initialized

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am making a mini state manager library for objects (because. don't ask.) and I want to use an approach like this (pseudo-code)

```
states = {}
when object is initialized {
if object.keys.states {
states[object.name] = object.keys.states;
}
}

/*
When object is initialized:
if object.keys.states exists:
states[object.name] = object.keys.states
*/
```

Is there a way to achieve this in typecript/javascript

Comment: Could you be more specific? The pseudo-code is vague and hard to read. Have you checked out the [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) object?

Comment: I think the pseudo-code is good with showing what it is meant for. Also the proxy object copies the entire object which I do not want. Plus, I need the objects name, Perhaps I could do some stuff with the constructor but I do not know the object constructor code neither do I know how to access the constructor.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by "*state manager library for objects*". (For what else?) And what do you mean by "initialised"? How do you distinguish this?

Comment: Is that "*when*" meant temporal or conditional?

Comment: clarification: by initialized I mean to define, like `let x = {};` the stage manager library for obej

Comment: First question is too hard to explain, by when I mean it basically just listens to any variable that's created and if it's an object it runs the code

Comment: If it's too hard to explain what you want to achieve, it's also too hard to answer your question :-) No, it is not possible to listen for variable instantiations or object creations. You will need to place an explicit function call there that invokes your library, like `let x = miniStateManager.register({})`

Comment: OK, i guess, still not what I wanted but better than nothing. Post your comment as a solution so I can accept it

Answer (score 0):

is this typescript? if this is typescript you could use a class and an interface to execute that code or a constructor inside a class

```
  class states {
  states: State[] = [];
  constructor(statesc?: State[])
  {
      if (statesc) {
          for(var state in statesc)
          {
              //no need to do objects keys if you can rotate trough the given parameter
              //btw only a class constructor can be called when an object is instantiated otherwise you need to do the 
              //logic after it has been created
              this.states.push(statesc[state]);
          }
      }
  }
    
}

interface State{
    id: number;
    name: string;
}

//then you can do this
let states = new States(states); and the constructor gets called
```

Comment: I need to use an object (reasons too long to explain), like this ```let component = {state: {count: 0, incrementCount: n => count += n;} markup: /*backquote*/<h1>${count}</h1> <button onclick="incrementCount(1)">increment</button>\/*backquote/*}```